# C# Sockets: client is not connecting to server in seprate computers

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Im new to c# sockets programing and im working on a little project of a server that sends strings for some clients. I made it by modifing [MSDN's Synchronous Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx) and [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx) Socket Example. 
When I run the server and the clients on the same computer,they work fine, but when I run the server on a computer and the client on another computer, a socket exception shows on the client(both computers are at the same network).
Now im not sure what to do: port forwarding? change the code?

server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace textweb
{
    class Program
    {
    static int counter = 0;
    static Socket[] _socket = new Socket[2];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        //running the server on the local host
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()); 
        Console.WriteLine(ipHostInfo.HostName);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, /*MyPort*/);

        try
        {

            listener.Start(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

            while (counter < 2)
            {
                while (!listener.Pending()) { }
                while (listener.Pending())
                {
                    _socket[counter] = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            bool _continue = true;
            while (_continue)
            {
                string m = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m);

                foreach (Socket soc in _socket)
                {
                    soc.Send(msg);
                    if (m == "exit")
                    {
                        soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        soc.Close();
                        _continue = false;
                    }
                }
            }




        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace textclient
{
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];


    try {

        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(/*server's ip*/); 
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,/*MyPort*/);
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        try {

            sender.Connect(remoteEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            bool _continue = true;
            while (_continue)
            {
                if (sender.Available>0)
                {
                    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    string a = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                    if (a == "exit")
                    {
                        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        sender.Close();
                        _continue = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString()); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString()); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    }
}
}
```

I hope the question was clear and you will answer it,
Itay

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution very fast.
I just port-forwarded the port im using to the server ip.
for example if server ip is 10.0.0.1 and port is 2222
I just needed to forward port 2222 in with "lan users" 10.0.0.1.
Thank you for your help anyway.